# In this Model what they are mentioning as getTypeId()

Tags: magento2, product, orders, shipping, modal

In this Model they had mentioned the getTypeId() but for what they mentioned as type id i can't understand can anyone please explain me.

> $orderItem->getProduct()->getTypeId()

what will be the result in this TypeId().

Folder Path : **/var/www/html/development/amt/vendor/magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui/Model**

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    declare(strict_types=1);

    namespace Magento\InventoryShippingAdminUi\Model;

    use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Model\GetSkuFromOrderItemInterface;
    use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\StockInterface;
    use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\StockRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\GetStockItemConfigurationInterface;
    use Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Model\IsSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductTypeInterface;
    use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;

    /**
     * Is source inventory of certain order is manageable
     */
    class IsOrderSourceManageable
    {
        /**
         * @var GetSkuFromOrderItemInterface
         */
        private $getSkuFromOrderItem;

        /**
         * @var GetStockItemConfigurationInterface
         */
        private $getStockItemConfiguration;

        /**
         * @var StockRepositoryInterface
         */
        private $stockRepository;

        /**
         * @var IsSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductTypeInterface
         */
        private $isSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductType;

        /**
         * @param GetSkuFromOrderItemInterface $productRepository
         * @param GetStockItemConfigurationInterface $getStockItemConfiguration
         * @param StockRepositoryInterface $stockRepository
         * @param IsSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductTypeInterface $isSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductType
         */
        public function __construct(
            GetSkuFromOrderItemInterface $productRepository,
            GetStockItemConfigurationInterface $getStockItemConfiguration,
            StockRepositoryInterface $stockRepository,
            IsSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductTypeInterface $isSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductType
        ) {
            $this->getSkuFromOrderItem = $productRepository;
            $this->getStockItemConfiguration = $getStockItemConfiguration;
            $this->stockRepository = $stockRepository;
            $this->isSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductType = $isSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductType;
        }

        /**
         * Check if source manageable for certain order
         *
         * @param OrderInterface $order
         * @return bool
         */
        public function execute(OrderInterface $order): bool
        {
            $stocks = $this->stockRepository->getList()->getItems();
            $orderItems = $order->getItems();
            foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
                $productType = $orderItem->getProduct()->getTypeId();
                if (!$this->isSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductType->execute($productType)) {
                    continue;
                }

                /** @var StockInterface $stock */
                foreach ($stocks as $stock) {
                    $inventoryConfiguration = $this->getStockItemConfiguration->execute(
                        $this->getSkuFromOrderItem->execute($orderItem),
                        $stock->getStockId()
                    );

                    if ($inventoryConfiguration->isManageStock()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning the product type: simple, configurable, virtual, etc

Comment: Thank you for your response bro

Answer (score 0):

The Type Id refers to the type of products in the order.

`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Api/Data/ProductInterface.php:169`

For each order item it could be set to any of the following product types, plus any custom product types that have been added to your build.

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::DEFAULT_TYPE = 'simple'
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE = 'simple'
\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE = 'configurable'
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_BUNDLE = 'bundle'
\Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped::TYPE_CODE = 'grouped'
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL = 'virtual'
\Magento\Downloadable\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE = 'downloadable'
```

If that product type does not allow stock management, it will skip the checks